# How to get the current viewed users uid

Tags: 7, users

If I am viewing a users profile page, how do I obtain and display (in a block) their uid? NOTHING to do with the current logged in user. I need to display the users id in a block on their page.

Answer (score 6):

If you are showing a standard drupal user profile page this should get you going:

```
  $user = user_load(arg(1));
  $user->uid; // access user id
```

This assumes the path is `user/uid`. If your path looks different adjust the `arg(position_in_path)` to your needs.

Comment: I am unsure why BetaRite uses the user ID (already in the path) to load the user object only then to output the user ID.  
Use this instead. `if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1))) $userid = arg(1);`

Answer (score 3):

A better option would be to use `template_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables)` and add the user id from here - that way you're not relying on any URL arguments (`arg()` is a recipe for fail).

Pop the following in your `template.php`

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {

  $account = $variables['elements']['#account'];
  //Add the user ID into the user profile as a variable
  $variables['user_id'] = $account->uid;
  // Helpful $user_profile variable for templates.
  foreach (element_children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['user_profile'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }

  // Preprocess fields.
  field_attach_preprocess('user', $account, $variables['elements'], $variables);

}
```

This will make the UID available to the `user-profile.tpl.php` template as a variable called `$user_id`.

This means that you can then copy `user-profile.tpl.php` from the *modules/user* directory to your theme directory and change it to the following:

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $user_id; ?>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
</div>
```

Obviously you'll want to style it and add extra DIVs and whatnot, but at it's most basic this will put the user id at the top of the user profile page.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the answer on @Jamie's question. Anyway, `user-profile.tpl.php` already has User Id available.

Comment: Aah...I missed the 'display in a block' part.  I did a `print_r` on the `$user_profile` variable and didn't see the UID there.  If it was part of the render array, then surely it would be rendered.  Either way, the above code works fine and does allow for the UID to be rendered onto the page.

Comment: Yup, just checked.  By default, UID is not part of the `$user_profile` render array.

Comment: nobody forbids you to `print $variables['elements']['#account']->uid;` in `user-profile.tpl.php`, but it's not the answer I think. Your code is useful, so I haven't downvoted it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function [menu_get_object('user')](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

Answer (score 0):

probably not the best approach in drupal 8 but this work

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $exploded_path= explode('/',$current_path);
    $uid=end($exploded_path);
    if (prev($exploded_path) =='user')
      $user=User::load($uid);
```

Answer (score -3):

as BetaRide in the page profile you can use arg(1) it will give you user profile and then you can use user_load()

Comment: OP says: NOTHING to do with the current logged in user. But global $user does give you exactly this.

Comment: yey I think the question need the logged in user sorry